# phalcon netbeans code completion MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, netbeans, phalcon, code-completion

It's possible code completion if I define in controller

```
$this -> view -> this_is_my_var = 'hello world'
```

And I write in view (.phtml file)

```
$this -> view -> this_is(...)
```

Netbeans show hints *this_is_my_var*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for this?

**PHP**

```
$this->view->this_is_my_var1 = 'hello world';
$this->view->this_is_my_var2 = new \Phalcon\Registry();
```

**View**

```
/**
 * @var string $this_is_my_var1
 * @var \Phalcon\Registry $this_is_my_var2
 */
```

Comment: This is manual solutions, because I must create comment with vars. I'm looking for automatic solutions which can prompt variables.